# WebRTC recording with AAC encoding

Tags: google-chrome-extension, encoding, webrtc, recording, mediastream

I'm recording screens and webcam video in a Chrome extension using [WebRTC](https://webrtc.org/)  but it appears the audio streams in my .mp4 videos are encoded with Opus which causes QuickTime to display an **Error -2048:** Couldn't open the file video.mp4 because it is not a file that QuickTime understands.

Is it possible to use a different audio encoding option supported by Quicktime?

Comment: Looking into the same thing, have you got any response on the same? 

I need to use AAC audio codec for my stream, can't work with Opus and would like to use WebRTC (MediaStreamRecord, RecordRTC) libraries for web browsers support.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe mp4 supports any audio codecs supported by WebRTC.

If possible I would use Matroska, that supports VP8/VP9/H264 and Opus/PCM which will cover pretty much all WebRTC calls.